# Category of profunctors compact closed?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

In the article "Coherence for compact closed categories", Kelly and Laplaza say

> The “category” of small categories and profunctors fails to be a compact closed category only because it fails to be an honest category with associative composition.

What composition are they talking about? What do they mean by an honest category?

Comment: Without checking the details, the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor) entry for profunctors describes composition of profunctors that gives a [bicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicategory) of small cats and profunctors. That suggest that the composition is only well-defined up to coherent isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

There's no consistent way to define the composition, as it involves taking a coend. The traditional way around this is to identify functors between small categories with cocontinuous functors between their free cocompletions, where the composition becomes the standard composition of functors. Unfortunately, the category of locally small cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors is not closed, as the categories of functors may not be locally small. This can be solved by viewing small categories abd profunctors as a compact closed bicategory.